# Disable New Relic from reporting when switching environments locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, newrelic

We use New Relic to monitor our Rails applications. Sometimes, when we are developing locally, we need to switch to a different environment to test things. We start up our server like so

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

Unfortunately, now our app starts sending data to new relic as though we added another machine to our production cluster.

**How can we disable the New Relic gem from sending data up to New Relic when we need to test settings locally under a different environment?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:  `NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false RAILS_ENV=production rails s`